# ORA-00936: missing expression using pipes

Tags: sql, oracle, select, pipe

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? I'm trying to use pipes and I plan to tidy it up to make it flow a bit more later in regards to the normal text bits but I want to know why it isn't working now to begin with.

```
    SELECT
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO ||'Customer Number'||
    CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME ||' First name '||
    CUSTOMER.SURNAME ||'Last name'||
    CAR.MAKE ||'Make'||
    CAR.MODEL ||'Model'||
    CAR.CAR_NO ||' '|| 
    CAR.PURCHASE_PRICE ||'Price Bought'|| 
    CAR.SOLD_PRICE ||'Price Sold'||
    CAR.SOLD_PRICE - CAR.PURCHASE_PRICE ||'Profit'||
    STAFF.FIRST_NAME ||' '||
    STAFF.STAFF_NO ||' '||

    AS "All sales in July 2015"

    FROM CUSTOMER, CAR, STAFF
    WHERE CAR.SOLD_BY_CUSTOMER_NO = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO AND SOLD_DATE                  between '07/01/2015' AND '07/31/2015' AND STAFF.STAFF_NO = CAR.SOLD_BY_STAFF_NO;
```

Comment: You have an extra || before the as

Comment: Ah great thanks. I've taken that out and now I'm getting ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Now you need parentheses around your subtraction - `(CAR.SOLD_PRICE - CAR.PURCHASE_PRICE)`. Without that you're creating a long string and then trying to subtract the purchase price from that string. (See [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators001.htm#BCFJDBDD)).

Comment: Brilliant! It works now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last pipe as below

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO ||'Customer Number'||
    CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME ||' First name '||
    CUSTOMER.SURNAME ||'Last name'||
    CAR.MAKE ||'Make'||
    CAR.MODEL ||'Model'||
    CAR.CAR_NO ||' '|| 
    CAR.PURCHASE_PRICE ||'Price Bought'|| 
    CAR.SOLD_PRICE ||'Price Sold'||
    CAR.SOLD_PRICE - CAR.PURCHASE_PRICE ||'Profit'||
    STAFF.FIRST_NAME ||' '||
    STAFF.STAFF_NO ||' '

    AS "All sales in July 2015"

    FROM CUSTOMER, CAR, STAFF
    WHERE CAR.SOLD_BY_CUSTOMER_NO = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO AND SOLD_DATE                  between '07/01/2015' AND '07/31/2015' AND STAFF.STAFF_NO = CAR.SOLD_BY_STAFF_NO;
```